# Read the entered phone number after SMS verification from Facebook Kit account

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

This might be a simple solution but I can't figure it out that how can I read the user entered "Phone number" in the SMS login field from Facebook account kit.
I am using facebook kit account SDK to verify the user phone number and want to read the user entered phone number after he successfully verifies his number.

I am using Android and want to just save the entered phone number locally in android for future purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the Account Kit login process completes you'll get back a result that will contain the phone number if an end user successfully verified their phone number:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android#handlereturn

Comment: Thank you. But I had to change my login type configuration from CODE to TOKEN and access my account details(phone number) by calling `AccountKit.getCurrentAccount`